# What articles are used for generic reference in French?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, articles

If I want to say

> Lions are beautiful

which of the following is correct?

> Lions sont beaux

or

> **Des** lions sont beaux

or

> **Les** lions sont beaux

How does *generic reference*, which is what I'm actually interested in, work in French? What articles, if any, are used for generic reference contexts such as the one in my example?

Comment: Pour exprimer à l'oral l'idée de ta phrase "lions are beautiful" un natif utiliserait probablement une phrase construite avec "'C'est": "C'est beau, un lion", "Les lions, c'est beau", "Un lion, c'est beau" etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ici, c'est *Les lions sont beaux* qu'il faut employer.

L'article défini *les* [s'emploie pour parler de tout l'ensemble des choses, des personnes que dénote le substantif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/les) (sens II. "Emplois génériques" - B. "Au pluriel").